# RSS feed in Exact Target email

Tags: xml, email, rss, exacttarget, ampscript

Really struggling with this one and ET support have been little help. I'm trying to build an RSS feed from the following site into an email:

feeds.feedburner.com/en-kaplanblog

I followed the guide in ET and built this code...

```
%%[Var @xml, @title,
Set @xml = ContentAreaByName("My Contents\zTesting and training\RSS") 
/*      This line specifies the content area from which the RSS content will
 be pulled for the email message. */

Set @title = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1) ]%%

<div style="border: 1px solid #444; background-color: #F7F7F7; margin: 
0.76em 0; padding: 0.76em;">%%=v(@title)=%%</div>
```

...just to test the functionality using the 'title' field. The email sends ok when I test, but there's just no content brought into the @title variable. Is this variable incorrectly targetted? Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot everyone!

Best,

James

Comment: This topic has been discussed quite a bit over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [Marketing-Cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [AMPScript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you. please check with this.

```
`%%[
/* @xml for your URL or content Area, means in @xml you will get the RSS feed data */
set @xml = HTTPGet(“YourURL;)

set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,”//item/title”,1)
```

/* In XML FEED there will be number of data which is repeated in title so we have printed in @title*/

```
If RowCount(@titles) > 0 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @titles DO
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),”Value”)
]%%

%%=v(@title)=%%

%%[ 
NEXT @cnt
ENDIF 
]%%`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to explain how it works.

Comment: I hope it will help you now